# Error with MLflow installation making it crash halfway through

Tags: python, installation, pip, apple-m1, mlflow

I have installed python on my M1 mac using 'brew install python'. I then did 'pip3 install mlflow', and the installation gets about halfway done, and then I get the following list of errors. I looked it up everywhere, and nobody seems to have the same issues as me. If anyone knows what's going wrong please respond below it would be greatly appreciated.

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 369, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 373, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 213, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 204, in _get_updated_criteria
    self._add_to_criteria(criteria, requirement, parent=candidate)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 438, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 524, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 68, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 48, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._install_build_reqs(finder)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 118, in _install_build_reqs
    build_reqs = self._get_build_requires_wheel()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 95, in _get_build_requires_wheel
    return backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 685, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return super().get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings=cs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 172, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 332, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 89, in _build_backend
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mesonpy'
```

Comment: @phd hey I fixed the formatting, my bad it's my first time using stack overflow. Let me know if you find the issue

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16974